# Local queue to save jquery ajax posts until network connectivity restored

Tags: jquery, ajax, networking, queue, local-storage

The app I am working on an app that makes ajax calls to the server updating values as they change - I dont't need any response from the server.  But I need to be sure the update gets made to the server database eventually.

The environment I am in provides for multiple connectivity problems - walkin coolers, old building etc.  In the future people will be taking tablets offsite for several hours and out of internet connectivity.

I would like a way to queue ajax queries (seems like the best way would be to use html5 local storage in case of power failures or whatever while away from the network).

Getting ready to write something to do this. I think I have enough of a handle on local storage and serializing ajax to do this.  But it seems like such a common problem that someone else already did the work.  Any suggestions on plugins, etc would be awesome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interesting in the lawnchair project: http://brian.io/lawnchair/adapters/

It has adapters for many different offline storage mechanisms.

[image: sorta like a couch except smaller and outside]